# ReactJS - Silently renew token with iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, access-token

I'm trying to wrap my had around authentication processes, and implement, every 60 minutes, a silent token renew in my React app, like so:

1. Create some watcher function, which checks the expiration time of
   the access token. If the token is about to expire, it is time to renew it.
2. Render an iframe tag, the src should be the same URL which you are
   using for redirecting to the Auth server, with one difference:
   change the return URL to a static file, let's call it redirect.html.
   The server should know about the user calling this URL, from the stored cookie, so it should just simply redirect you to the
   redirect.html file, now with a fresh access token.
3. In this redirect.html write a short script, which takes out the
   token from the URL and override it with the one you already have in local storage.
4. Destroy the iframe.

---

> Spotify page:

At Spotify dev page, I have my usual redirection URL saved, for when the token is first fetched from authorization URL server:

`http://localhost`

and then I add a new redirection URL for my iframe with Spotify as well:

`http://localhost/redirect_html`

---

> App

**App.jsx**

This is the component I have for silent renewal, so far, which I'm testing at `localhost/test-silent-renew` at my parent component, like so:

```
 <Route exact path='/test-silent-renew' render={() => (
     <SilentTokenRenew
     />
 )} />
```

---

> Component

And this is the actual refresh component:

**SilentTokenRenew.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


class SilentTokenRenew extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      renewing: false,
      isAuthenticated: false
     }
    this.currentAttempt = 0
    this.maxNumberOfAttempts = 20
    this.state.renderIframe = this.renderIframe.bind(this);
    this.state.handleOnLoad = this.handleOnLoad.bind(this);
  };

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.renewing !== nextState.renewing
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timeInterval = setInterval(this.handleCheckToken, 20000)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timeInterval)
  }

  willTokenExpire = () => {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('spotifyAuthToken');
    console.log('access_token', accessToken)
    const expirationTime = 3600
    const token = { accessToken, expirationTime } // { accessToken, expirationTime }
    const threshold = 300 // 300s = 5 minute threshold for token expiration

    const hasToken = token && token.accessToken
    const now = (Date.now() / 1000) + threshold
    console.log('NOW', now)

    return !hasToken || (now > token.expirationTime)
  }

  handleCheckToken = () => {
    if (this.willTokenExpire()) {
      this.setState({ renewing: true })
      clearInterval(this.timeInterval)
    }
  }

  silentRenew = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const checkRedirect = () => {
        // This can be e
        const redirectUrl = localStorage.getItem('silent-redirect-url-key')
        console.log('REDIRECT URL', redirectUrl)

        if (!redirectUrl) {
          this.currentAttempt += 1
          if (this.currentAttempt > this.maxNumberOfAttempts) {
            reject({
              message: 'Silent renew failed after maximum number of attempts.',
              short: 'max_number_of_attempts_reached',
            })
            return
          }
          setTimeout(() => checkRedirect(), 500)
          return
        }
        // Clean up your localStorage for the next silent renewal
        localStorage.removeItem('silent-redirect-url-key') // /redirect.html#access_token=......
        // // Put some more error handlers here
        // // Silent renew worked as expected, lets update the access token
        const session = this.extractTokenFromUrl(redirectUrl) // write some function to get out the access token from the URL
        // // Following your code you provided, here is the time to set
        // // the extracted access token back to your localStorage under a key Credentials.stateKey
        localStorage.setItem(Credentials.stateKey, JSON.stringify(session))
        resolve(session)
      }
      checkRedirect()
    })
  }

  handleOnLoad = () => {
    this.silentRenew()
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({ renewing: false })
        this.currentAttempt = 0
        this.timeInterval = setInterval(this.handleCheckToken, 60000)
        // Access token renewed silently.
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ renewing: false })
        // handle the errors
      })
  }

 generateRandomString(length) {
    let text = '';
    const possible =
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
  } 

       renderIframe = () => {
    const state = this.generateRandomString(16);
    const url = new URL('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=my_id&scope=user-read-currently-playing%20user-read-private%20user-library-read%20user-read-email%20user-read-playback-state%20user-follow-read%20playlist-read-private%20playlist-modify-public%20playlist-modify-private&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&state=rBZaR9s1gHchWEME')
    console.log('URL HREF', url.href)
    console.log(url.searchParams.get('redirect_uri'))

    url.searchParams.set(Credentials.stateKey, state)
    url.searchParams.set('redirect_uri', 'http://localhost/redirect.html') // the redirect.html file location
    url.searchParams.set('prompt', 'none')
    //window.location = url; 

    return (
      <iframe
        style={{ width: 0, height: 0, position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0, display: 'none', visibility: 'hidden' }}
        width={0}
        height={0}
        title="silent-token-renew"
        src={url.href}
        onLoad={this.handleOnLoad}
      />
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { renewing } = this.state
    return renewing ? this.renderIframe() : null
  }
}

export default SilentTokenRenew;
```

---

> HTML

And this is the code for my iframe:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>OAuth - Redirect</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Renewing...</p>
<script>
  // Get name of window which was set by the parent to be the unique request key
  // or if no parameter was specified, we have a silent renew from iframe
  const requestKey = 'silent-redirect-url-key'
  // Update corresponding entry with the redirected url which should contain either access token or failure reason in the query parameter / hash
  window.localStorage.setItem(requestKey, window.location.href);
  window.close();
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

I can see that if I do the following:

```
url.searchParams.set('prompt', 'none')
window.location = url; /// <-------
```

The new token is there, at browser url redirect.

But I don't seem to be able to make my `<script>` work at `localhost/redirect.html` file location, which is under the same root as the component.

There must be some problem with my `redirect.html` script, or file, setting my `requestKey`, because I'm console logging `redirectUrl` as `undefined` or `null`, if I use either

1. `const redirectUrl = localStorage.getItem('silent-redirect-url-key')`

   or
2. `const redirectUrl = localStorage['silent-redirect-url-key']`

---

> EDIT

Chrome goes silent, but Firefox tells me that:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: “deny” from “https://accounts.spotify.com/login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fac…prompt%3Dnone%26client_id%my_id”, site does not permit any framing. Attempted to load into “http://localhost/test”
```

I have a `nginx` proxy, where client is configured like so:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass        http://client:3000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
    proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
  }

  location /redirect.html {
    proxy_pass        http://client:3000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
    proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
  }
}
```

Is there a workaround for that limitation changing my nginx config above?

---

Or, if not, and only without framing I seem to periodically get this new token, like so:

```
const url = new URL('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=my_id&scope=user-read-currently-playing%20user-read-private%20user-library-read%20user-read-email%20user-read-playback-state%20user-follow-read%20playlist-read-private%20playlist-modify-public%20playlist-modify-private&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&state=rBZaR9s1gHchWEME')

window.location = url // <----
```

Can I extract this token with no prejudice to app usability, using scraping etc?

Comment: Could it be your condition here: `return !hasToken || (now > token.accessToken.expirationTime)` should it be: `return !hasToken || (now > token.expirationTime)` in `SilentTokenRenew .willTokenExpire()` ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem here, you can't redirect to that `redirect.html` or you are redirected, but you need help with writing the script for parsing the token and storing it to LS?

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue might be in your return condition in `SilentTokenRenew.willTokenExpire()`, specifically this: `(now > token.accessToken.expirationTime)`. **now > token.accessToken.expirationTime** yields false, so your function will likely always return false unless a token doesn't exist.

The `token` object looks like:

```
{
  accessToken: TOKEN,
  expirationTime: TIME,
}
```

That portion of your conditional should instead be: `(now > token.expirationTime)`.

Hopefully that helps you out.

Comment: strange... if I do what you suggest, I get the error above. If I keep `token.accessToken.expirationTime`, `willTokenExpire()` at least logs time and token.

Comment: I would check the [docs for URLSearchParams.set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set). Might need to create a URL object from you url string.

Answer (score 2):

1. In `silenwRenew` method, the `redirectUrl` needs to be retrieved from the `localStorage`, this is the URL what you are going to store in the `redirect.html` file, under the **same key**. So, create a key which you will use for both parts. For example:

   `const redirectUrl = localStorage['silent-derirect-url-key']`

   - you may need to use `localStorage.getItem('silent-derirect-url-key')`, but it should work with both ways.
2. In `redirect.html` file, use the same key, so for setting the URL to the store, use:

   `const requestKey = 'silent-derirect-url-key'`

Lastly, the method `extractTokenFromUrl` should be simple, something like this:

```
extractTokenFromUrl(redirectUrl = '') {
    let accessToken = null
    let decodedAccessToken = null
    const accessTokenMatch = redirectUrl.match(/(?:[?&#/]|^)access_token=([^&]+)/)
    if (accessTokenMatch) {
      accessToken = accessTokenMatch[1]
      decodedAccessToken = JSON.parse(atob(accessToken.split('.')[1]))
    }

    let expireDurationSeconds = 3600
    const expireDurationSecondsMatch = redirectUrl.match(/expires_in=([^&]+)/)
    if (expireDurationSecondsMatch) {
      expireDurationSeconds = parseInt(expireDurationSecondsMatch[1], 10)
    }

    return {
      accessToken,
      decodedAccessToken,
      expireDurationSeconds,
    }
  }
```

Ofc you can make the code nicer, but you get the idea.

Comment: thanks, my friend. there must be some problem with my `redirect.html` script, or file, setting my `requestKey`, because I'm console logging `redirectUrl = undefined` ou `null`, if I use either `const redirectUrl = localStorage.getItem('silent-redirect-url-key')` or  `const redirectUrl = localStorage['silent-redirect-url-key']`. any ideias?

Comment: if I use `window.location = url;`after `url.searchParams.set('prompt', 'none')` , redirect happens with new token, and I get it at `http://localhost/redirect.html#access_token=...`, but without that line nothing happens at `redirect.html`

Comment: At first, the localStorage under that key will be undefined, that is correct, since you haven't set anything there yet. You are setting it inside the `redirect.html` file, thats why you have `currentAttempt` inside that silentRenew method, for checking it multiple times if it is set already. I still assume that your problem is that the iframe won't load that redirect.html file correctly. Check it in your networking tab, look for `redirect.html` and if you click on it, its content should be `OAuth - Redirect`.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to put a port number to the redirect.html url? like `http://localhost:3000/redirect.html`, or you forgot to put the redirect.html file to the public folder? Or, you forgot to set up a proxy in your package.json for that `redirect.html`. Just putting here some ideas.

Comment: I have tried with Firefox instead of Chrome and I get this: `Load denied by X-Frame-Options: site does not permit any framing. Attempted to load into “http://localhost/test”.` Is there any workaround this?

Comment: maybe, since the iframe is being accessed via https, If the page (spotify) is https, you cannot load a iframe on that page that is not https.

Comment: apparently, I can get the refreshed token only if I go to window.location outside the iframe. is there a way of scraping out my token from there?

Comment: There is, but but the CORS has to be set on the server.

Comment: Really? How so?

Comment: I have it set on my `Flask` server, with `from flask_cors import CORS`,  `cors = CORS()`, and then `cors.init_app(app)`.

Comment: I meant the CORS on the that spotify auth server... you are rendering it into your iframe, that has to be allowed somewhere.

Comment: Bummer...hopeless, then!