# Docker ( React / Flask / Nginx) - Spotify Authorization Code

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, flask, spotify

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33031590/3451339) SO answer, I'm trying to implement [Spotify Authorization Code](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow), since I need the user to be permanently logged in.

Unlike Implicit Flow, in Authorization Code flow the app must provide client_secret and get a refresh token for unlimited access, and thus data exchange must happen **server-to-server**.

---

> Nginx Proxy

My backend server runs with `Flask` at http://localhost:5000, and my Frontend runs with `React` at http://localhost:3000.

Both services are behind a `nginx` reverse proxy, configured like so:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass        http://client:3000;
        proxy_redirect    default;
        proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
    }

location /callback {
        proxy_pass        http://web:5000;
        proxy_redirect    default;
        proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
    }
```

---

According to the answer above, I'm doing the following:

1. Supplying a button on my Frontend page that links to your
   https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/{...} URL.
   (this must not be an AJAX request call, or it will raise `CORS` issues)
2. The user will proceed to give my application the permissions specified in the `scope` parameter, and 
   will be directed back to the URL you've specified in the REDIRECT_URI parameter.
3. This is where you get the authorization code, which you can use in
   the https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token/{...} endpoint

---

> React

Here I supply the authorization button to the user:

```
render() {
    var state = generateRandomString(16);
    const Credentials = {
      stateKey: 'spotify_auth_state',
      client_id: 'my_id',
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:5000/callback',
      scope: 'playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private'
    }
    let url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';
    url += '?response_type=token';
    url += '&client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(Credentials.client_id);
    url += '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(Credentials.scope);
    url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(Credentials.redirect_uri);
    url += '&state=' + encodeURIComponent(state);


   return (
      <div className="button_container">
      <h1 className="title is-3"><font color="#C86428">{"Welcome"}</font></h1>
          <div className="Line" /><br/>
            <a href={url} > Login to Spotify </a>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

---

> Flask

Here is where I want the app be redirected to, in order to save tokens to database, and **ideally having another redirection back to my frontend afterwards**.

```
# spotify auth
@spotify_auth_bp.route("/spotify_auth", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def spotify_auth():
    #Auth Step 1: Authorization
    #  Client Keys
    CLIENT_ID =   os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID')
    CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET')
    # Spotify URLS
    SPOTIFY_AUTH_URL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
    #SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    SPOTIFY_API_BASE_URL = "https://api.spotify.com"
    API_VERSION = "v1"
    SPOTIFY_API_URL = "{}/{}".format(SPOTIFY_API_BASE_URL, API_VERSION)

    # Server-side Parameters
    CLIENT_SIDE_URL = os.environ.get('REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL')
    REDIRECT_URI = os.environ.get('REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL')
    #PORT = 5000
    #REDIRECT_URI = "{}:{}/callback".format(CLIENT_SIDE_URL, PORT)
    SCOPE = os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_SCOPE')
    STATE = ""
    SHOW_DIALOG_bool = True
    SHOW_DIALOG_str = str(SHOW_DIALOG_bool).lower()

    auth_query_parameters = {
        "response_type": "code",
        "redirect_uri": 'http://localhost/callback',
        "scope": 'user-read-currently-playing user-read-private user-library-read user-read-email user-read-playback-state user-follow-read playlist-read-private playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private',
        # "state": STATE,
        # "show_dialog": SHOW_DIALOG_str,
        "client_id": CLIENT_ID
    }
    url_args = "&".join(["{}={}".format(key, quote(val)) for key, val in auth_query_parameters.items()])
    auth_url = "{}/?{}".format(SPOTIFY_AUTH_URL, url_args)
    return redirect(auth_url)



@spotify_auth_bp.route("/callback", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def callback():
    # Auth Step 4: Requests refresh and access tokens
    CLIENT_ID =   'my_id'
    CLIENT_SECRET = 'my_secret'
    CLIENT_SIDE_URL = 'http://localhost'
    PORT = 5000
    REDIRECT_URI = "{}:{}/callback".format(CLIENT_SIDE_URL, PORT)

    SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"

    auth_token = request.args['code']
    code_payload = {
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": auth_token,
        "redirect_uri": 'http://localhost/callback',
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
    }

    auth_str = '{}:{}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET) 
    b64_auth_str = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(auth_str.encode()).decode()

    headers = {
        "Content-Type" : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
        "Authorization" : "Basic {}".format(b64_auth_str)} 

    post_request = requests.post(SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL, data=code_payload)

    # Auth Step 5: Tokens are Returned to Application
    response_data = json.loads(post_request.text)
    print ('RESPONSE DATA', response_data)

    access_token = response_data["access_token"]
    refresh_token = response_data["refresh_token"]
    token_type = response_data["token_type"]
    expires_in = response_data["expires_in"]

    template =  render_template("index.html")
    response_object = {
                'status': 'success',
                'message': 'success',
                'data': [{'access_token': access_token,
                          'refresh_token': refresh_token,
                          'token_type': token_type,
                          'content': template}]
                }

    return jsonify(response_object), 200
```

---

> Redirects whitelisted with Spotify

```
http://localhost:5000 
http://localhost:5000/callback
http://web:5000
http://web:5000/callback 
http://localhost/callback
```

When I click on the button with the first two redirects, however, I'm getting the error:

```
localhost refused to connect.
```

Why?

If I click the button having `http://localhost/callback` as redirect_uri I get:

```
KeyError: 'access_token'
```

---

What am I missing?

> **QUESTION**

I would like to have a Flask endpoint like the one above where I could fetch the access token (renewed if it is expired).

A solution that would dispense with Javascript code for auth and would be perfect. Is it possible with a containerized server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authorization code flow is not implemented like it should.
The beginning of this flow should be a request from the frontend (react) to the backend (flask). The backend is responsible to trigger the `302 Redirect` to the identity provider (Spotify) with the correct parameters.

```
@spotify_auth_bp.route("/auth", methods=['GET'])
def auth():
    CODE = "code"
    CLIENT_ID =   os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID')
    SCOPE = "playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private"
    SPOTIFY_AUTH_URL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
    REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost/callback"
    return redirect("{}?response_type={}&client_id={}&scope={}&redirect_uri={}".format(SPOTIFY_AUTH_URL, CODE, CLIENT_ID, SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI), code=302)
```

The frontend should be totally unaware of the identity provider, and the backend should not forward the `access_token` to the frontend, but rather generate its own tokens (ideally as a Cookie) when the user is authenticated against the identity provider.

You dont use `client_secret` at all on client side, and it should not be known by the client. As the name suggests, it's supposed to be secret, and it's no longer secret as soon as you include it in JavaScript code. By keeping the `client_secret` inside the backend, you totally hide it from the end-users (especially from the malicious ones).

That being said, the reason why you are observing this error is that the `POST` request which is supposed to contain the `access_token` in the response actually doesn't.

The reason is that `?response_type=token` is wrong, it should be `?response_type=code` in the initial request.

Source: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/

Here is an example of a callback endpoint:

```
@spotify_auth_bp.route("/callback", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def callback():
    # Auth Step 4: Requests refresh and access tokens
    SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"

    CLIENT_ID =   os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID')
    CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET')
    REDIRECT_URI = os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI')

    auth_token = request.args['code']
    code_payload = {
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": auth_token,
        "redirect_uri": 'http://localhost/callback',
    } 

    post_request = requests.post(SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL, data=code_payload)

    # Auth Step 5: Tokens are Returned to Application
    response_data = json.loads(post_request.text)

    access_token = response_data["access_token"]
    refresh_token = response_data["refresh_token"]
    token_type = response_data["token_type"]
    expires_in = response_data["expires_in"]

    # At this point, there is to generate a custom token for the frontend
    # Either a self-contained signed JWT or a random token
    # In case the token is not a JWT, it should be stored in the session (in case of a stateful API)
    # or in the database (in case of a stateless API)
    # In case of a JWT, the authenticity can be tested by the backend with the signature so it doesn't need to be stored at all
    # Let's assume the resulting token is stored in a variable named "token"

    res = Response('http://localhost/about', status=302)
    res.set_cookie('auth_cookie', token)
    return res
```

Comment: thank you. my secret is not exposed. it is just for exemple purposes. I use environment variables. the question -the implementation of a button at fronttend to /authorize endpoint, mentioned above, comes from someone who works on spotify. could you please use the whole authorizatoin flow, based on the flask code above? you answer, code-wise, is too brief.

Comment: Also `?response_type=token` is wrong, it should be `?response_type=code`

Comment: also, it is not true that cient_id and client_Secret must be passed as headers, as per docs: "An alternative way to send the client id and secret is as request parameters (client_id and client_secret) in the POST body, instead of sending them base64-encoded in the header." I've tried with enconding and headers, same error.

Comment: ah, yes, the problem was that: response_type=code redirected to `/callback`

Comment: Does it work for you? I've tried with the client ID and secret in the body, it didn't work, then I tried with the `Authorization` header and it worked

Comment: It works in the body for me, in the `/api/token` endopint. the thing is: how to call `/authorization` from React, other than using a button like the one above, because if I create another `/index ` flask endopint for that authorization  before `/callback` and call that from frontend, I will get `cors` issues. Spotify does not allow `ajax` requests from Frontend, thus the button. a nice answer would display the whole auth using flask endpoints only.

Comment: The right workflow is: React calls a flask `GET` endpoint (let's say `/auth`), then flask does `return redirect("https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=...", code=302)`. You won't have any CORS issue since `302 Redirect` is not a cross-domain request but a navigation to another domain

Comment: adding this code and all complementary code to your answer would be very welcomed and upvoted

Comment: I'm editing my answer with the redirect, but I'm not very familiar enough with python to provide a full tested solution, I was interested in your question because I like OAuth

Comment: I have edited the flask code necessary for both Spotify flask endpoints. you can work on it. I test them here.

Comment: The client token generation is something pretty opinionated (JWT?, random meaningless token? ...) and out of the scope of the initial question.

Comment: I use JWT in my app.

Comment: just one comment. please change redirect_uri to `http://localhost/callback` on your answer. the one you use does not work. proxy already has localhost set with `http://web:5000`. and, for completeness sake, you could add to your answer my `/callback` route as well, with a final `return redirect('http://localhost')` .both routes are needed for the whole auth. thank you, a lot

Comment: @8-BitBorges I've fixed my mistake on the callback URL, and added the callback endpoint, because this is a solution to your specific problem. But I'd just like to point out that if you return the `access_token` to the frontend, then you don't need authorization code flow, implicit grant flow is enough. Also, calling the `/auth` endpoint with XHR then returning JSON is not very standard. Usually, there is a navigation to `/auth` and the authentication process ends with a `302 Redirect` with the token in a Cookie, but that implies to lose the JavaScript context, which you probably dont want?

Comment: Implicit Flow is already implemented as a backup option. the problem is that user needs to be logged permanentely. and Implicit Flow needs token renewal. I've tried to implement that with an iframe, but redirect to iframe was forbidden by Spotify. if you know another way of token renewal, please let me know. see my question here [https://stackoverflow.com/q/60348097/3451339]

Comment: and access token wont be returned to frontend in this option. tokens will be saved there at back end. do you have some reference as to how to store them, as cookies or whatever? i have a sqlalchemy database